# $f \in C^2(\mathbb R)$ , $(f(x))^2 \le 1$ ; $(f'(x))^2+(f''(x))^2 \le 1 $ ; then is $(f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2 \le 1 $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, continuity

> Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb R)$ be such that $$(f(x))^2 \le 1 ;
>  (f'(x))^2+(f''(x))^2 \le 1 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$$  Then is it
>   true that $(f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2 \le 1 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ?

I haven't gotten anywhere with this problem . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: The most imaginative functions that are available to me say the answer could be YES. I think if the answer is negative then the counterexample to confirm it should be very sophisticated. That said, I do not rule out that someone could prove the result without using any counterexample (Without his permission to use his name, I think of Jack D'Aurizio maybe).

Comment: is there an intuitive way to understand this problem? maybe say as dynamics and energy conservation, etc...

Answer (score 10):

Let $g(x) = f^2(x) + f'^2(x)$. We want to show that $g$ is bounded by $1$ when $f^2(x) \leq 1$ and $f'^2(x) + f''^2(x) \leq 1$.

The extremal value(s) of $g$ are found at points $x_*$ where $g'(x_*)  = 2f'(x_*)(f(x_*) + f''(x_*)) = 0$. If $f'(x_*) = 0$ then $g(x_*) = f^2(x_*) \leq 1$ and if $f(x_*) = -f''(x_*)$ we have $g(x_*) = f'^2(x_*) + f''^2(x_*) \leq 1$.  $g$ is therefore bounded by $1$ at any local maximum point.

If $g$ has an infinite number of maximum points $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $x_n$ is unbounded in both directions then it follows that $g$ has to be bounded by $1$ for all $\mathbb{R}$.

Now assume (as suggested in the comments by Eric Thoma) there exist a $x_*$ such that $g(x_*) > 1$. We can wlog assume $g’(x) > 0$ for all $x>x_*$ as otherwise there exist a point where $g’(x) = 0$ and $g(x) > 1$ contradicting the result above (if $g'(x) < 0$ then the same argument can be applied to the function $g(-x)$ for which $g' > 0$). Since $g$ is bounded and strictly increasing for $x>x_*$ the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ exists and satisfy

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f^2(x) + f’^2(x) = a^2 > 1$$

Since $g'(x) > 0$ and $g$ is bounded we must also have 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} g'(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)(f(x) + f''(x)) = 0$$

Since $f,f',f''$ are bounded we must either have $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ or $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) + f''(x) = 0$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x) = 0$ then $a^2 = \lim_{x\to\infty} f^2(x) \leq 1$ gives us a contradiction and if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) + f''(x) = 0$ then

$$a^2 = \lim_{x\to\infty} f^2(x) + f’^2(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f''^2(x) + f’^2(x) \leq 1$$

also gives us a contradition. It follows that $g$ is bounded by $1$ for all $x$.

Comment: And how do we know $g$ has an extreme value ? And how do we know that that extreme value is a " global maxima "?

Comment: As observed by a user in a comment (appears to be  now deleted) $g$ is bounded , As $0\le g \le 2$ , but ; how do we know that it attains a global maxima ?

Comment: @Eric Thoma : why is $g'$ never zero to the right of $x_0$  ?

Comment: @EricThoma I added the missing argument and got to basically the same argument as you mention above. Since you were first to suggest it I'm ok with it if you want to answer it yourself (and I'll be happy to remove my answer). Just let me know.

Comment: You had the key piece! Anyway a completely rigorous proof is up, thanks to this discussion.